# granular controls inside application after authentication process

Tags: authorization, jwt, claims-based-identity, access-control, abac

We have a IdP which stores users and manages some sort of roles. However we want to have more granular controls on applications as well. What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: Did you look into Attribute based access control? Here is NIST's view on it - csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Attribute-Based-Access-Control

Comment: Also have a look at my answer here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/175729/29490